# send large json data in post request in redux

Tags: json, redux, http-post, large-data, body-parser

I need to send a large very large json data in post request.
I am getting 413 reponse after setting json limit at 200mb for bodyperser.
I am using nodejs at server and react and redux at front end

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have called twice to bodyParser.json() & bodyParser.urlencoded(), the problem is that the one with limit are after the calls without options, which defaults to 200kb. So when you POST something greater than 200kb that error will be thrown, since the first parser will not go to the next middleware.

You shouldn't call bodyParser[method] twice.

You can change your bodyParser properties like below

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'200mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    limit: '200mb',
    extended: true
}));
```

Comment: hey prabhu, thanks for reply.
as you said I have called twice bodyParser method is correct. I have used


app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'200mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true, limit:'200mb'}));
this code here app is expres object.


but I have tried after commenting second line. It didn't worked

Comment: are you getting this error in your local environment or production environment ?

Comment: in local environment

Comment: my app.js look like this:

Answer (score 0):

app.js file is :

```js
'use strict';
let express = require('express');
// let server = require('http').Server(app);
const app = express();
let createError = require('http-errors');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
let apiRouter = require('./routes/api');

require('./mongo_configuration/mongo')();
require('./mongo_models/index');
// app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));


app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');

// app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'200mb'}));
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true, limit:'200mb'}));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    limit: '200mb',
    extended: true
}));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api',apiRouter);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App web-server listening on port 3000');
    require('./scripts/index');
});
```

Comment: You can uncomment the app.use(myParser.json({limit: '200mb'}));

Comment: it worked after  putting this code
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    limit: '200mb',
    extended: true
}));`

at the place of `app.use(express.json());`